MAUI Android works in DEBUG but crashes in RELEASE
This question is not really about how to solve the issue (as I have already solved it) but I am kind of confused what is going on and what am I missing?
My app was working fine in a debug mode but in release mode the app crashed at point where a NFC tag was discovered and cached ndef message was read.
Here below is code that worked in DEBUG but the app crashed in RELEASE:
public void OnTagDiscoveder(Tag tag)
{
    NdefMessage ndefMessage = null;
    
    try
    {
        var ndef = Ndef.Get(tag);
        ndefMessage = ndef.CachedNdefMessage; // Probably some low-level null reference problem.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // omitted for brevity
    }
}

And here below is the fixed code that works fine in DEBUG and also in RELEASE:
public void OnTagDiscovered(Tag tag)
{
    NdefMessage ndefMessage = null;

    try
    {
        if (Ndef.Get(tag) is Ndef ndef)
        {
            ndefMessage = ndef.CachedNdefMessage; // Probably some low-level null reference problem is solved.

            // omitted for brevity
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // omitted for brevity
    }
}

I have some basics in C++ language and I understand that there is a difference between debug and release modes (the final assembler code differs in number of steps, in working with memory etc. - also perhaps in debug there can be some pointer helpers etc.) But do I get this concrete issue right that there are some low-level (perhaps C language based) errors that won't throw any high-level exception so that even in C# try-catch blog the application will fall? Because the way I have solved this problem was actually that I had to analyse the logcat (for both the DEBUG and RELEASE modes) and find out what the problem was from that - as no exception was thrown neither in DEBUG or RELEASE mode.
Here is a DEBUG logcat:

Here is a RELEASE logcat:

Can maybe someone explain me a bit better what is going on? Or at least redirect me to some sources? Is there some way how I can anticipate these kind of problems in the future? What should I be aware of to do / or not to do? Because solving this kind of issue was a really new thing for me and it took a few hrs (and basically it was just a null reference problem which is normally solved in minutes).

Apps work fine in debug mode, but in release mode there are often various problems. This is caused by the trimming option or AOT option enabled in our app in release mode.
By comparing the logs of debug mode and release mode, we found that there are some logs about AOT.
From document Native AOT deployment, we could find that

Publishing your app as Native AOT produces an app that's
self-contained and that has been ahead-of-time (AOT) compiled to
native code. Native AOT apps have faster startup time and smaller
memory footprints. These apps can run on machines that don't have the
.NET runtime installed.

And from document the limitations of Native AOT deployment, we should also notify some limitations for Native AOT.
And we could notify the fourth limitation(Requires trimming, which has limitations), if we click the document Linking a .NET MAUI Android app,we could find that:

The linker enables you to trim your .NET MAUI Android apps. When
trimming is enabled, the linker leaves your assemblies untouched and
reduces the size of the SDK assemblies by removing types and members
that your app doesn't use.
Linker behavior can be configured for each build configuration of your
app. By default, trimming is disabled for debug builds and enabled for
release builds.

So, by default, the app may strip out the necessary code in release mode, which can cause problems with the app.

You can try to disable AOT and set Trimming to None, and release again.
